# FilterService Liip Imagine Bundle

Tags: symfony4, liipimaginebundle

I'm trying to inject the `FilterService` into a constructor in order to be able to call `getUrlOfFilteredImage`.

However, I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot autowire service "App\Bll\PhotoService": argument "$filterService" of method "__construct()" references class "Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "liip_imagine.service.filter" service.`

How can I alias this class so I can inject the service?

I've also tried the old method of using `container->get(...)`, but container is null and I'm not sure if it is the correct approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

One solution should be to add class into config/services.yaml

```
services:
    Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService:
        # some settings
```

[Symfony service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)
[Service aliases](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/alias_private.html)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the service as @Bonewolf
in your services.yaml add

```php
services:
...
   Liip\ImagineBundle\Service\FilterService:
        alias: "liip_imagine.service.filter"
```

after in your controller use by injection your service

```
public function upload(FilterService $filterService,...)
{
$filterService->getUrlOfFilteredImage($request->files->get('upload'),'your filter imagine');
}
```